# Let $A(a_1,a_2),B(b_1,b_2)$. Determine the coordinates of the midpoint of the AB segment by calculating its position vector.

Tags: geometry

Let $A(a_1,a_2),B(b_1,b_2)$. Determine the coordinates of the midpoint of the AB segment by calculating its position vector.

**My attempt:**

Let $A(a_1,a_2), B(b_1,b_2)$  points in the plane.

Then the vector director of the segment $\bar{AB}$ is $AB(b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2)$

Here, i'm stuck can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are from $A$ and going to $B$, you "travel" the vector  $\overline{AB}$. But if you want to stop in the middle point, then you would not "travel" the entire vector just half of it, i.e. $\frac{\overline{AB}}{2}=(\frac{b_1-a_1}{2},\frac{b_2-a_2}{2})$. So, what happens if you travel from $A=(a_1,a_2)$ a vector $(\frac{b_1-a_1}{2},\frac{b_2-a_2}{2})$? you end up at the middle point given by $$M=\left(a_1+\frac{b_1-a_1}{2},a_2+\frac{b_2-a_2}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{b_1+a_1}{2},\frac{b_2+a_2}{2}\right)$$